# How to return file from same directory on different URL in Spring boot?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have simple AngularJS single page application and Spring Boot for back end. I need to return `index.html` on different URLs. I created this kind of controller:

```
@Controller
public class WebResourcesController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/sample", "/sample/pages"},  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

but request to ***`localhost:8080/sample/pages`*** returns status **404**. Still when I send request to ***`localhost:8080/sample`*** I get proper html file and page loads. I have my `index.html` in `resources/public` folder. I think ***`localhost:8080/sample/pages`*** request tries to find resource in `sample/pages` folder instead of `/`. How can I solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Could you give the head of the Class file (annotation @RequestMapping of the class). It is possible to have multiple url serving the same content.
The "index" means it will load the index.html... the requestMapping doesn't have any action on the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would configure a WebMvcConfigurerAdapter with a custom PathResourceResolver:

```
@Configuration
public class SinglePageAppWebMvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private ResourceProperties resourceProperties;

    private String apiPath;

    public SinglePageAppWebMvcConfigurer()
    {
    }

    public SinglePageAppWebMvcConfigurer(String apiPath)
    {
        this.apiPath = apiPath;
    }

    protected String getApiPath()
    {
        return apiPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations(resourceProperties.getStaticLocations())
            .setCachePeriod(resourceProperties.getCachePeriod()).resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new SinglePageAppResourceResolver());
    }

    private class SinglePageAppResourceResolver extends PathResourceResolver
    {
        @Override
        protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException
        {
            Resource resource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
            if (resource.exists() && resource.isReadable()) {
                return resource;
            } else if (getApiPath() != null && ("/" + resourcePath).startsWith(getApiPath())) {
                return null;
            } else {
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).info("Routing /" + resourcePath + " to /index.html");
                resource = location.createRelative("index.html");
                if (resource.exists() && resource.isReadable()) {
                    return resource;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's great about this is that it's reusable. You can `@Import` it into any project.

Comment: Wouldn't this have any kind of problems with getting other resources? For example `index.module.js`, `index.controller.js` or other files like that which are not in the main directory where index is located?

Comment: No, because those are obtained normally. This simply returns the content of index.html for paths that don't have resolvable resources.